# DOMDocument escaping end chars in PHP

Tags: php, dom, escaping

I have a problem with class DOMDocument. I use this php class to edit a html template. I have in this template this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
```

But after editing, although I was not editing this tag, it escapes the end char "/" and it doesn't work.
This is the script:

```
$textValue = $company.'<br />'.$firstName.' '.$lastName.'<br />'.$adress;

$values = array($company, $firstName.' '.$lastName, $adress);

$document = new DOMDocument;

$document->loadHTMLFile($dir.'temp/OEBPS/signature.html');

$dom = $document->getElementById('body');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
$dom->appendChild($document->createElement('p', $values[$i]));
}


$document->saveHTMLFile($dir.'temp/OEBPS/signature.html');
echo 'signature added <br />';
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is, that when I load the HTML template by method loadHTMLFile, and than save by method saveHTMLFile, so although that I was not edit the meta tag, this tag is anyway without the end char /. I use it for edit ePub format and it's not working when this end char is missing here.
Sorry for my bad english :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer provided by this question: [Why doesn't PHP DOM include slash on self closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145237/why-doesnt-php-dom-include-slash-on-self-closing-tags)

In short, `DOMDocument->saveHTMLFile()` outputs its internal structure as regular old HTML instead of XHTML. If you absolutely need XHTML, you can use `DOMDocument->saveXMLFile()` which will use self-closing tags. The only problem with this method is some HTML tags cannot use self-closing tags like `<script>` and `<style>` so you have to put a space in their content so that they don't use self-closing tags.

I would recommend just ignoring the issue unless it is mandatory that you fix it. Self-closing tags are a relic of XHTML and are [unused in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693939/self-closing-tags-void-elements-in-html5).