# Replace one HTML attribute with the content of another HTML attribute in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, preg-replace, domdocument

Say I have an HTML string with multiple occurrences like below:

```
<img scr1="xxxx.jpg" src="aaaa.jpg" other_attributes="some_values" />
```

I want to make the "src" attribute to be replaced by the value of the "src1" attributes inside the same tag. (so that in the example it would have `src="xxxx.jpg"` instead).

How can I achieve this with PHP?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DOMDocument`

```
<?php
$html = '<img scr1="xxxx.jpg" src="aaaa.jpg" other_attributes="some_values" />';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$images = $xpath->query("//img");
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($image->hasAttribute('scr1')) {
        $src1 = $image->getAttribute('scr1');
        $image->removeAttribute('scr1');
        $image->setAttribute('src', $src1); 
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

https://3v4l.org/524Al

**Result:**

```
<img src="xxxx.jpg" other_attributes="some_values">
```

**UPDATE**

from [Why doesn't PHP DOM include slash on self-closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145237/why-doesnt-php-dom-include-slash-on-self-closing-tags):

```
header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml');
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: thanks! But it's missing the closed tag slash for the img tag. It should end with /> , how can I make this happen?