# PHP: Producing HTML that is proper XML from DOM

Tags: php

I have a case where I'm using the DOM classes to produce HTML, but I need the resulting HTML to be proper XML. How do I alter the following script to make it echo `<br/>` or `<br />` instead of `<br>`?

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$element = $document->createElement('br');
$document->appendChild($element);

$nodes_xml = array();
foreach ($document->childNodes as $node) {
    $nodes_xml[] = $document->saveHTML($node);
}
$result = implode("\n", $nodes_xml);
echo $result;
```

And what changes (if any) do I need to make to the following script to make sure that the result of the above script is always loaded properly, without adding any additional tags?

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
if (!$dom->loadHTML($result)) {
    echo "Not properly formatted!";
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145473/61795 this looks like an interesting possible solution. I'd search for XHTML keywords related to PHP DOM.